# Need to be make a billboard entity have selectable call back function and maybe pop up info

Tags: javascript, html, cesiumjs

I have a Cesium map with a billboard entity which contains an icon.  We periodically update the location of the icon.

I need to make the icon selectable on the map, and be able call a callback function, and also maybe pop up some information about the entity.
Is there a clean way of doing this?

```
        updateMover: function (aoMover, aoPosition, aoHeading, aoYaw, aoPitch, aoRoll, aoView) {
            aoMover.point = undefined;
            aoMover.label.pixelOffset =  new Cesium.Cartesian2(0, -50);

            if (aoMover.billboard === undefined) {
                // If it moves, its not a fixed radar
                aoMover.billboard = {
                // image: '../images/Green.png', // default: undefined
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

An entity's [`name`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html#name) and [`description`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html#description) fields can be used to pop-up information about the entity.

```
aoMover.name = 'Plaintext human-readable short name';
aoMover.description = 'Full <strong>HTML</strong> description...';
```

The HTML can contain any styling or markup, but by default will be placed in a [sandboxed iframe](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) to offer some XSS protection from user-supplied data.  By default it is shown in a Cesium [`InfoBox`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/InfoBox.html) owned by the viewer, which owns the sandboxed iframe.  Here's a screenshot, showing the default InfoBox on the right-hand side:

[image: Sample InfoBox screenshot]

Getting notified when the selection changes is a little trickier, currently this is considered "private" behavior and may change without notice in a future version of Cesium (for example by introducing an official Event to fire).  But until an official path exists, you can use something like this:

```
Cesium.knockout.getObservable(viewer, '_selectedEntity').subscribe(function (entity) {
    if (Cesium.defined(entity)) {
        console.log('Selected ' + (entity.name || entity.id));
    } else {
        console.log('De-selected.');
    }
});
```